# cakephp3 afterSave callback error

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Whenever a new entity is created, the following error occurs.

`Warning (4096): Argument 3 passed to App\Model\Table\AccountsTable::afterSave() must be of the type array, object given, called in D:\Xampp\htdocs\vendor\cakephp\cakephp\src\Event\EventManager.php on line 268 and defined [APP/Model\Table\AccountsTable.php, line 18]`

afterSave code inside the model

```
public function afterSave(Event $event, Entity $entity, array $options) {

}
```

Anyone have any idea what's going on here?

Comment: Can you tell me what you want after save?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer. Should be CakePHP documentation bug here. Hope it helps someone. Link here: [http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#Cake\ORM\Table::afterSave](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#Cake%5CORM%5CTable::afterSave)

```
public function afterSave(Event $event, Entity $entity, $options) {
}
```

Comment: Can you give documentation link for your answer so helpful other user.

Comment: Is `$options` an ArrayObject? If so please submit a correction to the documentation.

Comment: Yes. Already submitted the correction. Hope they corrects it.

Answer (score 0):

add this line `use ArrayObject;`